# Running into For loop error in bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop

My bash script has a for loop that just does not seem to work and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
((: j = : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
```

For loop:

```
for ((j = $Frompointer; j > $Topointer-1; j--))
do
 echo "Print recovery points" | xargs >> Del.txt        
done
```

Not sure what's wrong with my for loop, any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `$Frompointer` is empty. `j = $Frompointer` is expanding to just `j =` which is a syntax error.

Comment: In this case, the error message should say **error token is "= "** (at least in my bash).